# What is the chronological order of the episodes of xxxHolic?

Tags: xxxholic

I've seen the second season so let's start from there. That's when it gets complicated.

Which episode came before which, and when?

I know there is a OVA called *xxxHolic Shunmuki* but it didn't interest me in particular. I also saw that there is a season called *xxxHolic ROU* but I did not understand what episodes it has (at the moment) or how many seasons are there in general.

Comment: Huh? Were the xxxHolic episodes out of order? Or are you just asking what order all of the seasons and OVAs go in?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 1st Season, 24 episodes
2. 2nd Season (Kei), 13 episodes

   - Movie "A Midsummer Night's Dream", This probably takes place somewhere during the 2nd season (60 minutes, essentially a long episode)
3. OVA Shunmuki, 2 episodes, also crossover with Tsubasa: RESERVoir CHRoNiCLE
4. OVA Ro, 2 episodes, occurs a significant amount of time after Shunmuki.

Comment: Is there any information (**only if it certainly**) that will be released to other more chapters?

Comment: @HashiramaSenju I haven't read the manga or know what state the story is in there, but it's certainly possible to continue the story eventhough there's a significant time skip. Unfortunately, I know nothing of any plans to make more xxxHolic. If it's going to happen, you're likely to find news about it on sites like Anime News Network or AnimeNews.biz